# adding a shell script to a configuration file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm pretty new to shell scripting and linux in general.  Basically, I need to change the configuration file for logging out so that when a user logs out, a certain shell script is run.

Now, I've located the logout configuration file and opened it with vi using this command

```
$ vi ~/.bash_logout
```

At this point, I'm experiencing some very weird behavior.  When I try to type a character, the cursor jumps around seemingly erratically.  What could this be due to?  I'm running the latest version of ubuntu.

And once I get that figured out, what's the command to run a .sh file from within this configuration file?

Comment: So... are you having trouble using vi then?

Comment: If the editor is really your problem, and all you need it for is to put a single command in your `.bash_logout`, you might as well do it from the command line.  For example, if your logout action is `echo bye` you could do `echo "echo bye" >>.bash_logout`.

Comment: On ubuntu, you should be able to type `edit ~/.bash_logout` and a new window will open with a 'nicer' text editor. Gedit, I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're having trouble with vi, try using `nano` instead. `nano .bash_logout`

If you do need to use vi for some reason, "i" will put the editor into insert mode, and ESC will take it out of insert mode when you're done. ":wq" will write and quit the editor.

To run a command, just put it in the .bash_logout file as you would type it on the commandline.

Comment: And remember to ensure that the script is executable, and if you do not use a full pathname to the script, then ensure it is stored in a location listed on your PATH.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: `.bash_logout` is like `.bashrc`, `.profile` and others. These don't need to be executable and they must be in the user's home. These files are not executed as normal scripts, they are executed with `source` (see `help source`) as if the user has typed the commands. The difference: Normal scripts cannot changes the local environment, cannot define `alias`es, cannot change the current working directory. The mentioned files can do that.

Comment: @A.H.  Yes - it is the script run from the `.bash_logout` file that must be executable and in an appropriate location.  The asker seems to be planning to have this execute in other people's environments, and I for one set my PATH the way I want (and would probably remove someone else's contributed `.bash_logout` from my home directory), so there may be problems with getting the script run.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Ok, NOW I understand. I've read over that part in the question. Thanks and sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

Some other useful commands:

- **a** insert after selected character
- **o** insert at next line
- **O** insert at previous line
- **r** replace a single character
- **R** replace mode
- **:q!** quit without saving
- **:w** save
- **:wq** save and quit

To get familiar with Vi and its brother Vim ("VI improved") I recommend the book "A Byte of Vim", you can read it online or download for free at http://www.swaroopch.com/notes/Vim

Comment: Don't forget the immensely memorable: 'type `l` (ell) to move the cursor right one character'.

Answer (score 0):

You can permanently change your editor option. To find out what your current one is, type this:

`export | grep -i edit`

To change it on Ubuntu:

`sudo update-alternatives –config editor`

On any other BASH prompt, just do this:

`export EDITOR="nano"`

Replace 'nano' with 'vi', 'emacs', or any other preferred editor. You can also add this to your .bashrc by typing the following:

`echo 'EDITOR="nano"' >> ~/.bashrc`